# onScrollStateChanged in RecyclerView called infinitely

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in which I am changing background of central item after every scroll. Hence I overrided onScrollStateChanged method with following code:

```
      @Override public void onScrollStateChanged(int state)
  {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(state);
    if (state == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
    {
      scrollCount++;
      Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onScrollStateChanged called in idle state: "+scrollCount+" times");
      if (mCenterItemChangedListener != null)
      {
        mCenterItemChangedListener.onCenterItemChanged(findCenterViewIndex());
      }
      int centerViewPosition = findCenterViewPosition();
      Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onScrollStateChanged: center view position" + centerViewPosition);
      smoothScrollToPosition(centerViewPosition);

    } else
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++)
      {
        if (i != findCenterViewPosition())
        {
          getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.llPeriodFrontLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.llPeriodBackLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Problem is it is being called infinitely and since I am snapping view to center. RecyclerView automatically scrolls till end and last element is considered as central element. As opposed to docs, which says it would be called only when state changes but I only scroll once.